How to get an array of custom-typed objects, returned by a function, with IDA Appcall
let assume we have a structure defined in local types:
struct Human {
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
};

and the prototype of the function i need to call:
const Human**__fastcall getHumans(const cusType2 *t, size_t *num);

when i try to create array (Appcall.array()) with Human* type. i get error.
when i try to do:
Human = function( t, num);


or
Human = object();
Human = function( t, num);

i only get the first object. that first object is good and typed good. i just need to get the whole array and loop through it. also, the "num" becomes "10", indicating 10 "Human"s are returned.
i also tried defining a structure having several "Human" in it and re-defined the function with that type. still getting only the first object.
there's also a chance of the return type being std::vector too.
tried searching stackoverflow and IDA pro IDC documentations.
